# Google Maps Android API. Authorisation failure

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, developer-console

I'm trying to set up a GoogleMap view in my app the map shows up blank so far. I get the following error in my LogCat:

```
01-14 00:23:47.471 17271-17639/? E/Google Maps Android API: Authorization failure.  Please see https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start for how to correctly set up the map.
01-14 00:23:47.491 17271-17639/? E/Google Maps Android API: In the Google Developer Console (https://console.developers.google.com)
                                                            Ensure that the "Google Maps Android API v2" is enabled.
                                                            Ensure that the following Android Key exists:
                                                                API Key: <My API key>
                                                                Android Application (<cert_fingerprint>;<package_name>): <MY:SHA:HASH>;<com.my.app>
```

On my `Google Developer Console`, I've enabled `Google Maps Android API` and I'm using the corresponding generated API key. The setting in my `AndroidManifest.xml` file looks like this:

```
<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/map_api_key"/>
```

Any idea where I might be going wrong? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is the sha set correctly within your settings under Google Developer Console??? MY:SHA:HASH;com.my.app says the sha was set to "MY:SHA:HASH: and com.my.app was the package you said that API was being used for.. obviously the hash is not correct that isn't a SHA-128bit hash

Comment: I've edited the hash here. I used the actual hash shown in the LogCat in my Google Developer Console. And I've used my app's real app id.

Comment: I see makes sense :P, I was just making sure you didn't copy and paste from an example you found online or something.